# Is performing mathematical operations on String variable a good idea?

Tags: java, string, bigdecimal

Is it a good idea to hold the numeric values in `String` variable in an object (also passing in methods and returning as String) and later while only operating it convert in `BigDecimal` and operate?

The intention to use in method signature and pojo's is that operation can be performed in `double` or any other type the implementor prefers to

For e.g.

```
public String operate(String value1, String value2){
    BigDecimal val1 = new BigDecimal(value1);
    BigDecimal val2 = new BigDecimal(value2);
    return val1.multiply(val2).toString();
}
```

Or it is just an overhead?

Would it affect performance?

Comment: Yes... why don't you just store that in BigDecimal

Comment: Does performance matter in your case?  Do you know that performance will be a problem?  If not, I suggest you do it the simplest way you can.

Comment: BTW It is almost always best to only convert a value to a String when you want to display it. (Unless a String is a natural type for it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bad idea from two standpoints:

1. All of the operation will require you to translate from/to string representation
2. Memory overhead is enormous.

Consider this example. An ordinary `int` occupies 4 bytes in memory. An `int` represented as a `String` can occupy up to 72 bytes:

- 16 bytes -- object overhead,
- 4 bytes -- cached hash code
- 8 bytes -- reference to char array
- 24 + 2 * 10 bytes -- char array itself (10 digits max)
- up to 8 bytes for padding

It is 18 (!) times more than a primitive representation of an `int`.

Comment: agree for translation purpose. but considering `int` is not always the case. most operations requires `double` and its better to operate in `BigDecimal` than `double`. So comparing memory usage isn't it almost similar in `BigDecimal` and `String`?

Answer (score 2):

Converting from one format to other format is always overhead. Store it in the format so you can perform all operation on it

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why could it be good idea. "[Stringly Typed](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html)" is not very good thing to do. And yes, BigDecimal holds a number more compact, as byte arrays, and also optimises to hold small values in a `long` value. String would be as two-byte character decimal representation.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of problems with doing this.  First, there is the overhead of creating and destroying extra objects, at least one for ever conversion to/from a String.  Depending on how many times this happens, it could be significant.  Second, every time you convert from String-to-numeric and back, you risk parsing issues and such.  Last, you circumvent any build-in checks and balances Java provides in regards to type casting and such.

My personal opinion is that you should minimize conversion when possible, and store data in the most specific object/primitive you can.  I think this makes the code easier to read, easier to maintain, and easier to troubleshoot when there is a bug.